# Removing a specific value off of firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am setting up a social media app and currently working on a way to create authentic usernames(no duplicates) for the user to enter, similar to that of Instagram.

The problem that I'm facing is that I can't find a way to delete the users previous username(in case anyone else wants to use it). The way that my database is setup for usernames is like:

Usernames
  - username:"testUsername"

I have attempted to delete the code using this

```
let usernameRef =  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Usernames").child("username").child(usersCurrentUsername)
usernameRef.removeValue(completionBlock: {(error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print("There was an error in removing the current username\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print(ref)
                print("The child was removed")
            }
        })
```

I capture the users current username via snapshot in the viewdidload and store it in usersCurrentUsername. 
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
let usernameRef =  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Usernames").child("username");
usernameRef.removeValue();
```

Note that if the child of Usernames is only the username, the Usernames node will also be deleted.